# Powershell search by single and multiple keyword

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I have some commands below that do not give any output when looking for specific keywords in Windows Logs using PowerShell.

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application"} | Select-String "Information"
```

However, if I only run `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application"}`, there are many entries with Information keyword. `Select-String -pattern "Information"` also does not work.

Ideally I'd like to search for multiple keywords in the above scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application"} | ? { $_.leveldisplayname -eq 'Information' }
```

The `Information` you're looking for is a property of the object. The `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet returns a collection of objects, so you need to add the `Where-Object` or `?` to filter on the `LevelDisplayName` object property.

To answer your new questions:

The `leveldisplayname` is going to be Information, Error or Warning. You can add either of these or use logic to combine them. In order to search for keywords in a message, using a regex is probably the best approach:

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application"} | ? message -imatch "keyword1"
```

To search multiple keywords, you can modify the regex using the OR `|` operator:

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application"} | ? message -imatch "keyword1|keyword2|foo|bar"
```

If you wanted to search for all Error messages containing "foo" or "bar" you could do;

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application"} | ? { ($_.message -imatch "foo|bar") -and ($_.leveldisplayname -eq 'Error') }
```

Comment: Ok @arco444. How do I search in message too? And how can I search multiple keywords?

Comment: @SanchitRasiya Multiple keywords in a message or multiple display levels (e.g. `Information` and `Error`)?

Comment: Q#1 How can I search in single word in leveldisplayname & message too. Q#2 How can I search multiple keywords in leveldisplayname & message?

Comment: Updated, does that help?